# What is the alternative method of jquery "scrollHeight" in salesforce-lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

I want to get a height of a class in salesforce lightning.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("simpleclass")
```

Output showing **{}**
How can i retrieve dom and get the height of that?

Answer (score 2):

Lightning framework allows to use methods of `document` object. The only thing, it does it vie SecuredDocument. You can check methods that can be called from Locker API  from this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)

so, to get `scrollHeight` of `div` element you can do  the following:

**test.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">Some content..</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <lightning:button label="Get Scroll Height" onclick="{!c.getScrollHeight}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**test.css**

```
.THIS .content{
    height: 800px;
    width: 2000px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: coral;
}

.THIS .container{
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

test.Controller.js

```
({
    getScrollHeight : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
        for (var i=0; i<contents.length; i++) {
            console.log("scroll height is:" + contents[i].scrollHeight);
        }
    }
})
```

so, once you click `Get Scroll Height` button, browser console prints `820` - got scroll height of div.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried exact code but its returning me "contents "[]" "
var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("container")
 console.log("contents "+ JSON.stringify(contents));

Output contents "[]"

Comment: @SubhasisGiri  try `console.log("contents ", contents);` and you will see that debug outputs **Proxy** object. If you want to read more how to debug correctly proxy objects you can read these: [q1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207422/avoid-proxy-objects-in-debug-statements-for-a-lightning-component), [q2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222343/why-are-my-javascript-objects-equal-to-proxy). [q3](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220693/how-to-unproxy-lockerservice-wrapped-data-for-debugging-via-console-log)

Comment: @SubhasisGiri and [Secure Wrappers for Global References](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/security_global_access.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `component.find` to get the element.

```
var div = component.find('scroll_container');
```

And get the scroll height like so:

```
div.scrollHeight
```

This answer may help -> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/190154/39652.